# Using Model to establish inner join between tables

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfwheels

I'm trying to set up a relationship between two tables, *articles* and *categories*. It is a 1-to-1 relationship where `articles.category_id = categories.id`. I have the following set up.

**controllers/home.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent extends="Controller">

    <cffunction name="index">

        <cfset qFeaturedArticles = model("articles").findAll(
            where="show_homepage = 1",
            include="categories",
            order="homepage_order"
        ) />

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

**model/categories.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent extends="Model">

    <cffunction name="init">
        <cfset hasOne("articles", foreignKey="category_id") />
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

**model/articles.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent extends="Model">

   <cffunction name="init">
    <cfset belongsTo("categories", dependent="nullify") />
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

This is the error I am getting.

Invalid CFML construct found on line 4 at column 49.ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

=

The CFML compiler was processing:

- An expression beginning with belongsTo, on line 4, column 16.This message is usually caused by a problem in the expressions structure.

  A cfset tag beginning on line 4, column 10.

  A cfset tag beginning on line 4, column 10.

The specific sequence of files included or processed is: \cfusion\wwwroot\foo\index.cfm, line: 4

Comment: what is on line 4 of `index.cfm`?

Comment: It's a `cfinclude` to wheels/index.cfm; i.e. no code there that was manipulated on my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I would like to point to categories.cfc model. If you are specifying `hasOne` relationship then in that case the code should look like as follows:

```
<cfset hasOne("article", foreignKey="category_id") />
```

Note that instead of `articles` you need to put `article` in case of `hasOne`.

But, literally speaking, the relation between categories and articles should be `one to many`. I mean a category can have many articles.

So the categories.cfc should be written as follows:

```
<cfcomponent extends="Model">

<cffunction name="init">
    <cfset hasMany("articles", foreignKey="category_id") />
</cffunction>
```